# Condense code: SetupSequence returning different values on successive calls

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am testing a method that calls other methods. I have a working test that uses this method to generate my mocked connection object:

```
    private Mock<IDatabaseConnection> MockOutGetControlDocInfoData()
    {
        Mock<IDatabaseConnection> mockConn = new Mock<IDatabaseConnection>();
        List<Mock<IDbCommand>> mockCmds = new List<Mock<IDbCommand>>();
        List<long> vals = new List<long>() { 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
        foreach (long val in vals)
        {
            mockCmds.Add(CreateMockCmdObjectWithReturnValue(val));
        }
        mockConn.SetupAllProperties();
        mockConn.Setup(c => c.Conn.ConnectionString).Returns("What the heck.");
        mockConn.SetupSequence(c => c.CreateCommand(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(mockCmds[0].Object)
            .Returns(mockCmds[1].Object)
            .Returns(mockCmds[2].Object)
            .Returns(mockCmds[3].Object)
            .Returns(mockCmds[4].Object)
            .Returns(mockCmds[5].Object)
            .Returns(mockCmds[6].Object)
            .Returns(mockCmds[7].Object)
            .Returns(mockCmds[8].Object)
            .Returns(mockCmds[9].Object);
        return mockConn;
    }
```

I'm not pleased with the SetupSequence Returns, which seems like it ought to be part of a loop, but I don't know how to put more than one Returns into the SetupSequence. Any idea for improvement?

For now at least, I'm fine with manually creating my list of test values.

It shouldn't be relevant, but I can provide the `CreateMockCmdObjectWithReturnValue` code if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var sequence = mockConn.SetupSequence(c => c.CreateCommand(It.IsAny<string>()));
foreach (var cmd in mockCmds)
{
   sequence = sequence.Returns(cmd.Object);
}
```

Comment: Is this Linq? It doesn't build when I put it into my code. A Long array doesn't seem to have any `Select` method.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. The key was getting that `sequence` variable.